# Windows 10 file explorer is not opening folders by default, Atom has replaced it and I cant seem to change it back

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, atom-editor

Atom seems to have made itself the default program for everything, even opening folders and making me have to right click < open, every time I look through my files. I dont want to uninstall Atom because of all the plugins I have, so does anyone know another way of getting file explorer back as the default when I double click?

Open with when right clicking is not an option.

I am using windows 10, please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Windows 10 "Folder" and "Directory" association Registry Files from [this page](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)

Download, unzip them and extract the .REG files to a folder. Right-click each REG file and choose Merge. Alternately, you can open the Registry Editor and then using the Import option from the File menu, to merge the REG file contents.

The relevant settings are under these keys if you want to compare the settings with another system:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder